# Hello World @OneToMany in a WebService Session Bean with JPA Entities

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, soap, persistence

Ladies and Gents,

I'm trying to setup a simple @OneToMany Hello World type example using SOAP based Web Services.  The setup is fairly straightforward: two entities in a parent/child relationship.  Orders is the parent.  OrderRows is the child.  ALL of this was setup with wizards using JDeveloper 11g.  I did not modify the code other than changing the name of the session bean.

The problem occurs when I try to express this relationship by including the @OneToMany annotations and the related List operations (set, add, remove) in the Orders.java file.  If I comment those out and do not return the associated List containing OrderRows, all is well.  Include the @OneToMany and nothing returns.  This is probably some kind of simple configuration error, but the problem is I'm not getting any errors in my console when I right-click my session bean and select "Test Web Service", choose the getOrdersFindAll() operation, and click "Send Request".  All I get is a nice little snarky message saying "No content to display."  So I'm just sitting here ... at 2 AM in the morning ... wondering "Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?"

I've looked over some sites such as http://biemond.blogspot.com/2011/08/expose-your-session-bean-with-jax-ws.html and read through the Java EE 7 tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxws.htm#BNAYL all to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Or would anyone have some good websites to get some practical examples?

MySessionBean.java

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless(name = "MySession", mappedName = "HelloWs-HelloService-MySession")
@WebService(name = "MySessionBeanService", portName = "MySessionBeanServicePort")
public class MySessionBean {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "HelloService")
    private EntityManager em;

    public MySessionBean() {
    }

    /** <code>select o from Orders o</code> */
    public List<Orders> getOrdersFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Orders.findAll").getResultList();
    }
}
```

My Orders.java Entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@NamedQueries( { @NamedQuery(name = "Orders.findAll", query = "select o from Orders o")     })
public class Orders implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal orderId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orders")
    private List<OrderRows> orderRowsList;

    public Orders() {
    }

    public Orders(BigDecimal orderId, String refName) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(BigDecimal orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public List<OrderRows> getOrderRowsList() {
        return orderRowsList;
    }

    public void setOrderRowsList(List<OrderRows> orderRowsList) {
        this.orderRowsList = orderRowsList;
    }

    public OrderRows addOrderRows(OrderRows orderRows) {
        getOrderRowsList().add(orderRows);
        orderRows.setOrders(this);
        return orderRows;
    }

    public OrderRows removeOrderRows(OrderRows orderRows) {
        getOrderRowsList().remove(orderRows);
        orderRows.setOrders(null);
        return orderRows;
    }
}
```

My persistence.xml.  Note that while the double jdbc looks funky, I'm pretty sure that's not the source of the problem since removing the @OneToMany annotation and related methods works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="HelloService">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/app/jdbc/jdbc/HelloConnDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>helloservice.Orders</class>
    <class>helloservice.OrderRows</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource"     value="java:/app/jdbc/jdbc/HelloConnDS"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update**

I've tried a couple more things.

1) This appears to be a distinctly Web Service type problem.  If I remove the Web Services bit and inject the session bean ( @EJB ) into a jsp's backing bean, the @OneToMany relationship works fine.

2) I thought perhaps the OrderRows @ManyToOne was causing an infinite loop so I set its fetch type to lazy.  No luck.

**Update #2**

Success!  I was close with the infinite loop hunch earlier. Here's the solution.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child implements Serializable {
...
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private Parent parent;
```

The important items to note are the XmlAccessorType and the XmlTransient annotations.  That tells the XML transcriber not to bust into an infinite loop going back and forth between the two entities.  Rumor has it there's also a @XmlInverseReference annotation that's even better but I can't get it to work.